# React - Changing password using Firebase Functions and Admin does not work

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I am having a bit of trouble with how to handle Firebase Functions using Firebase Admin. I am trying to edit a user's password using Admin and I took the example given by Firebase which is this one to adapt into a function:

```
// userDataObject = { password: userData.inputPassword }
exports.updateUserData = functions.https.onCall(
  async (userId, userDataObject) => {
    return await admin
      .auth()
      .updateUser(userId, userDataObject)
      .then(userRecord => {
        console.log(userRecord);
        return { isError: false };
      })
      .catch(error => {
        return { isError: true, errorMessage: error };
      });
  }
);
```

While I can easily delete a user using functions using Admin, I can't do the same when editing users's password. The function above seems to not be working. I try to login with the new password, but it does not work. Yet if I try to login with the old password, it works. The function returns no error except that if, by using Google Chrome and if I inspect the Network tab, it gives me an error related to verifyPassword:

`https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=...`

I did not set up a serviceAccount for the admin as the Google Firebase documents stated that it's not required. I have seen the log to see what userRecord returns, but it seems that nothing is wrong except for passwordHash and passwordSalt which are undefined.

Do you have any idea about why is this not working?

**Edit**: 
Here is how the user invokes this function (userData is listed into the updateUserDatabase function):

```
  async updateUser(userData) {
    if (userData.inputPassword) {
      let updateUserRegister = firebase
        .functions()
        .httpsCallable("updateUserData");
      const userDataObject = {
        password: userData.inputPassword
      };
      return await updateUserRegister(userData.id, userDataObject).then(
        async result => {
          if (result.isError) {
            return result;
          } else {
            return updateUserDatabase(userData);
          }
        }
      );
    } else {
      return updateUserDatabase(userData);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show how the client is invoking this function.  Also show in debug logs the values of the inputs to this function. Your function is also not returning an error status code to the client, so it will not appear as an error in the network tab.  You should also log the return value of the function in the client and show that here as well.

Comment: You were right @DougStevenson. It was the invoke that was wrong. I had to use an object instead of sending two different variables. Thanks for pointing that one out! You can send an answer if you want so that I can pick it up as the correct one.